Docker container exits despite "ng serve --host 0.0.0.0"
I'm trying to run an angular app inside a docker container. The docker container exits shortly after the command "ng serve --host 0.0.0.0" is executed.
docker-compose.yml:
services
  frontend:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./docker/Dockerfile-frontend
    command: sh -c "cd public; npm install && npm run start"
    container_name: frontend-mol
    environment:
      - PORT=4200
    networks:
      - fullstack
    ports:
      - 4200:4200
    volumes:
      - ./:/app
    working_dir: /app

  networks:
    fullstack:
      driver: bridge

package.json:
"scripts" : {
    "start": "ng serve --host 0.0.0.0"
}

I did not alter the angular.json file. This is a fresh installation of Angular 17, I'm just trying to make a "hello world" app running in the container. What am I missing here?
Logs:
2024-05-20 12:38:04 > public@0.0.0 start
2024-05-20 12:38:04 > ng serve --host 0.0.0.0
2024-05-20 12:38:04 
2024-05-20 12:38:04 Please update your Node.js version or visit 
https://nodejs.org/ for additional instructions.
2024-05-20 12:38:04 

Dockerfile:
FROM node:16-alpine
RUN apk update && apk add python3 make g++


Does the container produce any logs that might help identify the problem?

Unfortunately not (I updated my question accordingly).

Your volumes: are overwriting absolutely everything in your image with host content.  If your Dockerfile has a RUN npm install line, the volumes: are overwriting that with the host's node_modules directory.  From the error message it seems like the underlying Node versions don't match.  If you delete the volumes:, working_dir:, and command: overrides to use what's built into the image, does it work better?  (You also should not need container_name: or networks: in normal use.)

Please add your Dockerfile. You can remove the network, working_dir and volumes stuff.

I intend to use the same docker-compose file for running a database and a backend, hence the volumes and working_dir (sorry for not making that clear in the beginning). I'm confused, because this setup worked perfectly on another project I did. It was not Angular V17 though, but it feels like I'm overseeing something here.

The problem was the Node version indeed. Using Node v 18 in favour of v 16 solved the problem.
